# Positioning a WidgetGroup in LibGDX

Tags: java, widget, libgdx, scene2d

I'm using a HorizontalGroup in LibGDX which works fine. I want to create a row of tiles. But when I try to position the group using setPosition() method, it doesn't position as I hope, that is to say, it doesn't render using my "y" value. Here is the code:

```
a = new Tile(missingwords.getAM().get("a2.png", Texture.class), "a", 3);
b = new Tile(missingwords.getAM().get("a2.png", Texture.class), "a", 3);
c = new Tile(missingwords.getAM().get("a2.png", Texture.class), "a", 3);
a.setSize(50, 50);
b.setSize(50, 50);
c.setSize(50, 50);
submitGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
submitGroup.addActor(a);
submitGroup.addActor(b);
submitGroup.addActor(c);
submitGroup.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - submitGroup.getMinWidth()) / 2, 0);
stage.addActor(submitGroup);
```

Here is my Tile code:

```
public class Tile extends Actor {
private String letter;
private int points;
private Texture texture;

public Tile(Texture tileTexture, String letter, int points) {
    this.letter = letter;
    this.points = points;   
    texture = tileTexture;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

As you can see, I use:

```
submitGroup.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - submitGroup.getMinWidth()) / 2, 0);
```

This means that it should render at y = 0. However, take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

The tiles are out of the screen and I don't know why. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting thing: I have printed `getY()` value in the constructor and is `-25.0`. I'm confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the reason is the default alignment in the [HorizontalGroup](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/HorizontalGroup.java): `Align.center`. Because of this the Tile y positions are -25.0 (which is the Tile actor's height / 2). So for example if you would create a Tile with height of 100 then the y position of the tile in your HorizontalGroup would be -50.

I see two ways of positioning the tiles like you want it:

1. Fixing the Alignment of the HorizontalGroup to bottom: `submitGroup.align(Align.bottom);`
2. by just setting the y position of the HorizontalGroup to `25` instead of `0`;

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I didn't know that default alignment was `Align.center`. But, `center` in accordance with the stage?

Comment: You can check the source code of [HorizontalGroup](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/HorizontalGroup.java) ;-) Actually I just figured out that there exists a bottom() method, so this should work as well: `submitGroup.bottom();`